# Android Studio - Lots of errors after reopening project

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I've been working on an app that I published to the play store yesterday, but when I reopened it this morning to make some changes, there's lots of errors in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, `activity_main.xml` & `styles.xml` files.

Edit: Here's the files & errors

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/the_wv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Errors:**

- Lines 2, 3 & 4: URI is not registered
- Lines 5, 6 & 7: attribute:xxxx is not allowed here
- Line 9: Element WebView is not allowed here

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/mainColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Errors:**

- Lines 6-9: Cannot resolve symbol 'xxxxxx'

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appname">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Errors:**

- Line 2: URI is not registered
- Lines 6, 7, 9, 10, 11 & 13: Attribute xxxxxx is not allowed here
- Line 14: Unresolved class 'MainActivity'

Any ideas why it might be throwing all these errors all of a sudden?

Comment: Please share the errors as well.

Comment: Try clean, rebuild, + sync project gradle files. Also, you can try restarting Studio by : File >> Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: I've edited my question with my code & errors. I tried to clean & rebuild but that doesn't seem to have fixed any of the errors

Answer (score 1):

You can try invalidating Android Studio cache.

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate & Restart

Comment: Thanks @Ali, I've just tried that but it doesn't seem to have worked

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project and rebuild again using this steps:

Step 1: Build -> Clean Project

Step 2: Build -> Rebuild project

Comment: can you share your project link, after uploading on drob box ? f

Comment: try to invalidate caches and restart